# How to share a same session object among UI and Java class?

Tags: jsf

in JSF, we define a lot managebean as session scope in Faces-config.xml. I am wondering can we share the same session object among UI and Java class? 
Example:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>abcBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.abc.com.ui.manage.AbcBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Can I get the abcBean in Java class, such as via FacesContext?

Please advise.

Comment: Session scoped JSF managed beans are stored as HTTP session attributes. Thus, you can also obtain a session scoped JSF managed bean from an HTTP session the usual way you obtain a session attribute from an HTTP session -- using the bean name as a key but the requirement is not pretty clear especially in terms of "*UI and Java class*".

Answer (score 0):

if i missunderstanding you, then sorry.

you can get any ManagedBean this way(Injection):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AnotherBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{myBean}")
    private MyBean myBean;
    ....
    ....
    // you have to implement the this setter!!!!!
    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myeBean;
    }
}
```

**OR**: (from/in any Java Class)

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(context == null)
            return null;
        else
            return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
    }
```